# Debian goes into Busybox after forced UEFI install

Tags: debian, debian-installer

While installing [Debian Stretch testing](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/), the installer asked if I wanted to "[force UEFI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226119/installing-debian-force-uefi-what-does-it-affect/235013)" during install. I chose "Yes" because when I did not, GRUB loader would fail to install.

After choosing "yes" and completing install, I booted up into Debian. But I got these screens. See attached images.

[image]
[image]

What is going wrong? What error(s) must I resolve to correctly boot into Debian?

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/817660/214223).

Comment: As the error message says, it can't find the root device (the harddisk you installed Linux on). The reason for this is not visible (probably in the messages that came before). You also have a lot of ACPI (information provided by the BIOS) errors, which is not good, and may or may not be the reason it can't find your harddisk. I'm not familiar with the "emergency" busybox shell, but try typing `dmesg` to see if you can get the missing messages, or try to capture the messages that come before, so we can see what's going on.